# Symfony upgrade 3.3 to 3.4 service not found

Tags: php, symfony

Trying to upgrade a project from Symfony 3.3 to 3.4. I've done `composer update symfony/symfony --with-depdencies` and added `public: false` to my `services.yml` file.

Now when I run my PHPUnit tests, I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException : The service "templating.loader.cache" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating.loader.wrapped".
```

Any ideas why this happens? I can't find any Google results or any Symfony documentation references for this at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was found to be caused by overriding the definition of `templating.loader.cache` to `public` in a compiler pass class to allow access during functional tests.

Based off code here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/8097

tl;dr do not do this:

```php
final class TestCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /** {@inheritdoc} */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        foreach ($container->getDefinitions() as $id => $definition) {
            $definition->setPublic(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead limit the services you make public to the ones you actually require.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you prepared your code for private services you shouldn't use the public: false tag. That is used to mark services as private. Probably somewhere in your code you have something like `$var = $container->get('example');` which calls a public service. You can read more [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default).